# LWC -> APEX Decimals are not received correctly

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I'm saving data from a LWC via APEX. When I send the decimal, in LWC it is correctly send as 1.55. But Apex receives 155.

[image]

```
handleSave(event) {
    this.showLoading = true;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event.detail.draftValues));
    saveItems({ oi : event.detail.draftValues })
    .then(result => {
```

This reults in

```
[{"salesQuantity__c":"1.55","Id":"802Fg000000EMK1IAO"},{"salesQuantity__c":"0.45","Id":"802Fg000000EMK3IAO"}]
```

And APEX receives

```
11:44:17:007 USER_DEBUG [19]|DEBUG|(OrderItem:{Id=802Fg000000EMK1IAO, salesQuantity__c=155}, OrderItem:{Id=802Fg000000EMK3IAO, salesQuantity__c=45})
```

Can somebody point me into the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: Please be make sure data type of salesQuantity__c is having decimal places allocated

Comment: It has not. But the value before on loading the LWC was also a decimal. And I changed the decimals to three decimals. APEX then receives "155.000" as quantity.

Comment: The result with three decimals and the values 1,5 and 0,5:
12:21:13:009 USER_DEBUG [19]|DEBUG|(OrderItem:{Id=802Fg000000EMK1IAO, salesQuantity__c=1.000}, OrderItem:{Id=802Fg000000EMK3IAO, salesQuantity__c=0.000})

Comment: We'd need to know more about how the table is set up. The JSON does *not* look correct--number properties should not be quoted. `"1.55"` is a string having four characters, while `1.55` is a number equaling 1.55 units. By passing in the numbers as strings, that's probably causing the problem you see here.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox,  this is the data table construct for the field:
 {
        type: 'number',
        fieldName: 'salesQuantity__c',
        label: 'Quantity',
        typeAttributes: { minimumfractiondigits : 3, maximumfractiondigits : 3 }
    },

And the input comes from the orderItem Object via APEX.